# css swap images with sizing

Tags: css, image

I have searched here, couldn't seem to find a solution. I know 'how' to essentially do mouseovers with jQuery if I use an actual "image" object, and have the image resized properly, I'm just trying to figure out if there is a way to do the same thing with CSS and use a specific class with background URL.

Here's my code & css:

```
.sample #img_id {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: url('sample.gif') left no-repeat top;
}

.sample #img_id:hover {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: url('sample-mouseover.gif') left no-repeat top;
}
```

and then my HTML code:

```
<div class="sample">
  <div id=img_id></div>
</div>
```

Now - if the image is say 200 pixels by 200 pixels - the image does NOT resize. (I.e., it will 'overflow'). I was expecting the image to be resized to 80px x 80px.

I have also tried this:

```
.sample img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: url('sample.gif') left no-repeat top;
}

.sample img:hover {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: url('sample-mouseover.gif') left no-repeat top;
}
```

and then my HTML code:

```
<div class="sample">
  <img src=sample.gif>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work either. The 'initial' image is "resized" properly (i.e., to 80 x 80 px) - but with the mouseover, the image would be 200px x 200px (i.e., no resizing).

How do I get my sample image properly resized/scaled to fit within the 80x80px on a mousever via CSS? (Like I said, I figured it out via jQuery, I just figure there should be an easy solution with CSS, and not quite sure just how to get it resized properly).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking into [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)?

Comment: thanks, that was it! (the background-size).

Comment: I'd have to add it as an actual answer. :-) Which I've done now, in case you want to officially accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property allows you to change the dimensions of the background image, [unless](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) you need it to work in IE8 and perhaps Opera Mini.

Answer (score 0):

possibly syntax, it's working on this [fiddle](http://%3Cscript%20async%20src=%22//jsfiddle.net/mattbehnken/xf93Lw3k/embed/html,css,result/%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

Comment: thanks, link doesn't work (for the fiddle) - I figured it out though (your demo doesn't have the background-size, but if I add that, it works a-ok).

Comment: ha sorry it was late at night. Glad you got it figured out. link to fiddle that you don't need anymore., https://jsfiddle.net/mattbehnken/xf93Lw3k/